# On the linearly independence of infinite exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Let $U$ be some non-empty open subset of $\mathbb C$. Suppose I have an holomorphic function $f$ defined by the series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{2\pi i nz}$ where $a_n\in\mathbb C $ for every $n$ and $z\in U$.

> Now say that $f(z)=0$ for every $z$. Is it true that we have $a_n=0$ for every $n$?

I ask this since we know that if we take a finite set of exponentials then they are $\mathbb C$-linearly independent functions, but passing to the infinite case seems not so clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V=\{e^{2\pi i z} : z \in U\}$. Then V is an open set (by Open mapping Theorem). Let $g:V \to \mathbb C$ be defined by $g(z)=\sum_0 ^{\infty}a_nz^{n}$. Then g is the sum of a convergent power series in V and $f(z)=g(e^{2\pi i z})$ If f=0 on U then g=0 on V and hence the coefficients in the power series expansion are all 0.

Comment: I think you should start the series of $g$ from $n=0$ and make clear why $V$ is open. After this, I will accept your answer as the official one. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Blacksmith Open Mapping Theorem of Complex analysis says any non-constant analytic function maps open sets to open sets. A proof can be found in books of Conway, Rudin etc.

Comment: yes sorry but I didn't mean that. The set $U$ could be non-connected so we cannot apply the open mapping theorem in the way you mentioned. We need to know that $z\to e^{2\pi i z}$ is a nowhere locally constant function and this maybe is more tricky since the complex exponential is not injective.

Comment: The theorem I have stated does not require connectedness. $e^{2\pi i z}$ is not constant on any non-empty open set because its derivative does not vanish anywhere. Please read the statement of Open Mapping Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the series converges to $0$ on $U$.  Then in particular the terms are uniformly bounded on $U$.  Since $\left|e^{2\pi i n z}\right| = e^{-2\pi n \text{Im}(z)}$ for $n \ge 0$, that says that if there is $z \in U$ with $\text{Im}(z) = r$, there is a constant $C$ such that $|a_n| \le C e^{2\pi n r}$ for all $n$.  Using this, we find that the series converges uniformly on the half-plane $H_s = \{z: \text{Im}(z) \ge s\}$ for all $s > r$, and the sum $f(z)$ is analytic there.  By the identity theorem for analytic functions, $f(z) = 0$ on all of $H_s$.

Now suppose $a_m$ is the first nonzero term.  For $\text{Im}(z)$ sufficiently large, easy estimates give $\left| \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n e^{2\pi i n z} \right| < \left|a_m e^{2\pi i m z}\right|$, implying that $f(z) \ne 0$, contradiction.